# where should my index.html be? django

Tags: filesystems, django, indexing

I have a friend working with me preparing some web services in a virtual server of mine,
he is in a different time zone, and can't talk to him right now,

i have access to the server, with ssh, sftp

i need to upload a file to the folder where index.html is,

the system is configured with apache for django

I have found different locations with the index.html

including where i looked as a "normal" location?

```
/var/www/mysite
```

so , the site works fine, 
but if i upload a file to the above folder, `"uploadedfile.txt"`
I cannot see the file there, 404

www.mysite/uploadedfile.txt

so , how can i find the folder for the index.html?

thanks!

Comment: It'll be wherever you configured it to be when you set the system up.

Comment: so why the down votes?, shall I know what is the configuration file?, is an obvious thing?

Comment: You shall know what is the configuration file, since you set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" location is used mostly by PHP-powered and static websites. Django is a whole different beast. In a typical Django setup any file you upload to the web server will be ignored (i.e. it will not be statically served) no matter where you upload it.

Since you apparently don't understand how Django works, you'd better wait for your friend to come online, before you break anything. If you are interested in learning how Django works, you can read the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) or the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/).